# How to change default location for Download... in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use VSCode to work remotely and I love the feature in which I can download a remote file directly to my local drive. However, the default location used to be my home directory, but now it automatically opens to my `~/.ssh` folder, which is slightly annoying. Does anyone know how to change the default location of "Download..." option in VSCode? It must be possible and I must have accidentally changed it somehow? Thanks!